# Не получается управлять toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

есть `Activity` со следующим кодом:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.leftcontent, new Requests());
        ft.commit();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.bringToFront();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

При загрузке нового фрагмента я пытался отключить `toolbar` таким образом:

```
getActivity.getActionBar.hide
```

но вылетает ошибка. Подскажите как сделать правильно?

Comment: `getActivity().getActionBar().hide()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

раз вы используете `setSupportActionBar()`, то надо использовать аналогичный геттер

`((AppCompatActivivty)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide()`

Comment: а сам фрагмент тоже должен быть из SupportLibrary или нет? у меня просто на 1 фрагменте виден toolBar а на следующем фрагменте нет... хотя по умолчанию он ведь должен быть виден на всех фрагментах,если проинициализирован в активности?

Comment: не обязательно, но лучше не смешивать в приложении и стараться использовать что-то одно

Comment: а обращаться к элементам toolbar также как actionbar ? tvTitle = (TextView) getActivity().getParent().findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

Comment: Я бы лучше  так сделал   
`toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`  

и потому уже в toolbar искать их   `toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)`

Comment: спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 5):

```
toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide
toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show
```

Ну или так:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();  // for hiding
getSupportActionBar().show();  // for show
```

Если работаете во фрагменте, то так:

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide(); //To hide
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().show(); //To Show
```

Comment: почему мне доступно только getActionBar()? getSupportActionBar() такой метод не доступен..

Comment: @Сергей а toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE) не помогает?